# Issue with HTML5 Notification and permission

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications, html5-notifications

I'm trying to use the new HTML notification API...
I'm still stuck in the request authorization phase;
when user click on a button it's executed the function:

```
// this is all inside a click handler
var fn = console.info;

window.Notification.requestPermission(function(grant) {
    fn(grant);          
});
```

When i tryed this for the first time in chrome, a chrome's message came out asking me if i want to concede the Notification grant to my localhost web site... I said no (just to test even this case). Then I tried again, but that message from chrome never came out.

My question:
If the user change opinion about notification, how could enable notification for a website?
Maybe do I've to change something in the chrome settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage and re-allow notifications in Chrome by going to `Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Scroll down to Notifications` - here you can manage which sites are allowed to show notifications and which are not.

***Update:***

As mentioned by @ivan_vaz in the comments, it is also possible to configure this as well as other permissions by clicking the favicon of the website in the address/navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you... this helped me, and the question was about just this... but if perhaps do you know a way to check again for permission, even if the the website is in the list of the blocked site, this will help me (and probably many others) a lot

Comment: I have googled a bit (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1076392?hl=en, https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications), and it seems that after the user has "blocked" the notification, you cannot force a new request. From that point, the user will have to manually re-enable notifications for that site. It would have been nice with a way of asking the user again, but on the other hand, if that was possible, it might also be possible to use it in a way that would be more distracting than useful.

Comment: Yes, you are right, probably some websites will abuse of that possibility... thanks.

Comment: The user can also re-allow notifications by clicking on the favicon at the website